# XML and XSL file output as HTML file

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a XML-file and a XSL-file and I want to get as output a HTML-file but I do not exactly know how to proceed to get a well formated HTML file. Do you have any websites where I can read how this is working?
Futhermore, I post my codes maybe I already have some mistakes.

Thank you in advance.

Natalie

XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Test_4_css.xsl"?>
<tapete>
<category name="MOBILE ICONS">
    <icon>
    <assetid>001</assetid>
    <title>car_setup</title> 
    </icon>
    <icon>
    <assetid>002</assetid>
    <title>remote_car_status</title>
    </icon>
    <icon>
    <assetid>003</assetid>
    <title>remote_lock</title>
    </icon>
</category>
<category name="HUMAN ICONS">
    <icon>
    <assetid>001</assetid>
    <title>car_setup</title> 
    </icon>
    <icon>
    <assetid>002</assetid>
    <title>remote_car_status</title>
    </icon>
    <icon>
    <assetid>003</assetid>
    <title>remote_lock</title>
    </icon>
</category>
</tapete>
```

XSL-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles4.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<xsl:apply-templates />
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="category">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
 <p>
<xsl:for-each select="icon">&#160;
<img150><xsl:value-of select="assetid"/></img150>
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </p>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Last time I looked HTML did not have an element named `img150` so I am not sure where you picked that up as HTML. In any case, if you use XSLT to generate HTML, you need to know HTML well to insert it. The XSLT processor helps with the serialization according to HTML rules with `output method="html"` but you will have to use known HTML elements for that to make sense.

Comment: Thank you. The img150 was a mistake by me.